# ¿Cómo se obtiene el valor de una $_SESSION['...']?

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar php con conexión a mysql y me mi objetivo es crear una tabla de la base de datos un cliente pero antes de esto obtengo el valor de una id y la guardo con ``$_SESSION
de la siguiente manera:

```
$consulta = "SELECT COD_USUARIO, TIPO_USUARIO FROM usuarios where USU_USUARIO = '$usuario' and  PASS_USUARIO = '$contrasenia'";
   $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
   $filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

   session_start();
   $_SESSION['usuID'] = $filas['COD_USUARIO'];
```

a continuación el resultado del var_dump realizado a $filas
[image: var_dump($filas)]
en otro documento php quiero obtener el valor de lo que se guardó para poder usarlo en un INSERT INTO

```
session_start();
      $usuID = $_SESSION['usuID'];

      $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (CI_CLIENTES, NOMBRE_CLIENTE, APELLIDO_CLIENTE, COD_USUARIO) VALUES ('$cedulaCL','$nombreCL','$apellidoCL', '$usuID')";
      $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

hasta el momento me sale null en la variable a la que se le asigna el valor grabado y por ende me dice que está mal la sentencia sql

**¿De qué manera puedo obtener el valor de `usuID` para poder asignarlo a una variable y que posteriormente pueda utilizarlo en la sentencia para mysql?

Comment: si haces un `var_dump($_SESSION)` que obtienes?

Answer (score 1):

Simplificando a lo concerniente a tu pregunta, `$_SESSION` es un array asociativo. Para acceder a una de sus variables, te basta con acceder a la llave correspondiente a dicha variable; En tu caso `$_SESSION['usuID']` Puedes hacer con ello lo mismo que una variable. Asignar dicho valor a otra, imprimirla ...

La linea

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (CI_CLIENTES, NOMBRE_CLIENTE, APELLIDO_CLIENTE, COD_USUARIO) VALUES ('$cedulaCL','$nombreCL','$apellidoCL', '$usuID')";
```

puedes cambiarla por:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clientes (CI_CLIENTES, NOMBRE_CLIENTE, APELLIDO_CLIENTE, COD_USUARIO) VALUES ($cedulaCL,$nombreCL,$apellidoCL, ".$_SESSION["usuID"].")";
```

Al manejar sesiones, suele ser recomendable que `session_start()` sea **lo primero** en cualquier archivo PHP donde necesites manejar sesiones.

Comment: realice los cambios que me recomendaste pero al probarlo en el navegador me salto un error relacionado a error de syntaxis

Comment: Las comillas puedes quitarlas de las variables, pero son necesarias para acceder a las variables en arrays asociativos, con lo que se han de concatenar entre strings. Editada la respuesta conforme a ello. No sé por qué no me dí cuenta en el momento.